# How many Hamiltonian cycles are there in a graph with n vertices?

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

How many eulerian cycles are there in a graph with n vertices?  The way that I see it there would be $\frac{n!}{(n!)(n-n)!}$ but that simplifies to 1 cycle and I know that there are more cycles than that.  What am I missing here? In this case the order of the vertices does not matter.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a complete graph?  If not, you need to know what graph it is.  In the complete graph $K_n$ where $n$ is even, there are no Eulerian cycles because each vertex has odd degree.

Comment: It is assumed that you can already make a eulerian cycle and every vertex must be used.

Comment: It still depends on which graph it is.  The number of (directed) Eulerian circuits on $K_{2n+1}$ is [OEIS sequence A135388](https://oeis.org/A135388), which doesn't seem to have a known closed form expression (see the McKay and Robinson paper referenced there).

Comment: How about non-directed?  (directed means the path a,b,c,d is not the same as d,c,b,a right?)

Comment: Each non-directed circuit corresponds to two directed circuits.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean Hamiltonian cycles?

Comment: Yes, I mean Hamiltonian cycles, sorry I couldn't clarify earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of hamiltonian cycles in a graph is $\frac{1}{2}(n-1)!$ since the graph is un-directed you do not have a choice for the first vertex and every point after that is $(n-1)(n-2)...$ or $(n-1)!$ and since there are 2 ways to choose the same vertex you end up with $\frac{1}{2}(n-1)!$.

Comment: Your argument seems to assume that you can move from any one vertex to any other. Are you assuming the graph is complete? If not, I think there is a problem. If your graph is an $n$-cycle with $n \geq 3,$ then your graph has only two Hamiltonians, regardless of the size of $n.$ I am counting a cycle and its reverse as two distinct circuits.